# Get Request using mongoose and Express

Tags: database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to fetch the existing sample_mflix database from mongodb. At first I created a model for the movies collection.
This is my schema for movies

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    plot: {
      type: String,
    },
    genres: [
      {
        type: String,
      },
    ],
    runtime: {
      type: Number,
    },
    cast: [
      {
        type: String,
      },
    ],
    num_mflix_comments: {
      type: Number,
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
    },
    countries: [
      {
        type: String,
      },
    ],
    released: {
      type: Date,
    },
    directors: [
      {
        type: String,
      },
    ],
    rated: {
      type: String,
    },
    awards: {
      wins: {
        type: Number,
      },
      nominations: {
        type: Number,
      },
      text: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
    lastupdated: {
      type: String,
    },
    year: {
      type: Number,
    },
    imdb: {
      rating: {
        type: Number,
      },
      votes: {
        type: Number,
      },
      id: {
        type: Number,
      },
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
    },
    poster: {
      type: String,
    },
    writers: [
      {
        type: String,
      },
    ],
    tomatoes: {
      viewer: {
        rating: {
          type: Number,
        },
        numReviews: {
          type: Number,
        },
        meter: {
          type: Number,
        },
      },
      lastupdated: {
        type: Date,
      },
    },
  },
  { collection: "movies" }
);

const movies = mongoose.model("movies", movieSchema);
module.exports = movies;
```

this is my route to get all the movies from database

movieRoutes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const movies = require("../models/movieModel");

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  //res.send("Movie List");
  try {
    const allmovies = await movies.find({});
    res.json(allmovies);
  } catch (error) {
    res.json(error);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

But I'm unable to get any data in Postman. I'm pretty sure that the route is called but Postman loads forever and does not fetch.

How to fix this ?

Comment: Can you do a console.log() before and after the await movies.find({})
Please share the console.log results and check if both are called or one is called or none is called

Comment: Actually the thing was the database was too large to load instantly, I actually waited for 40 seconds so I had to use limit. Thanks for reaching out and helping me. One favor though, How can I learn and enhance queries in mongoose

Comment: Official documentation is great https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html.